# Invalid Use of Property in VB6 Error. How to fix this?

Tags: properties, vb6

```
Private Sub aTbBar_Change()
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    With con
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;persist security info=false;data source=" & App.Path & "\Event_Participants.accde"
        .Open
    End With


    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        Set .ActiveConnection = con
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .Source = "select * from Participants"
        .Open


        'check from table if user and pwd matches
        If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            While Not rs.EOF
                If rs!Bar_Code_No = Val(Me.aTbBar) Then
                    Me.aTbName = rs!Full_Name
                    Me.aTbSection = rs!Section
                    Me.aTbArrtime = Time()
                End If
                rs.MoveNext
            Wend
        End If

        .Close
        Set rs = Nothing

    End With

    'save to the database
    'check from table if user and pwd matches

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        Set .ActiveConnection = con
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Source = "select * from Participants"
        .Open


        If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            rs.MoveFirst
            While Not rs.EOF
                If rs!Bar_Code_No = Val(Me.aTbBar) Then
                    .Update
                    rs!Arr_Time = Me.aTbArrtime
                End If
                rs.MoveNext
            Wend
        End If

    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Invalid Use of Proper error always occur when I type in to that textbox name aTbBar
The error occurs at Me.aTbName = rs!Full_Name. Can you help me on this one. Sorry, im new in this forums and in VB. I really need help

Comment: Can you at least mark the source line, where the error occurs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't see a question being asked here. You've not described a problem, marked a section of code that's the issue, or asked any question whatsoever. Please edit your question to provide some information, so we can try and help you solve whatever problem you're having.

Comment: the error occurs at
Me.aTbName = rs!Full_Name

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with that code. Please post the definition of `Me.aTbName`.

Comment: Can I send you the project file. Im kinda really new here. I don't even know what you meant by definition of Me.aTbName

Comment: He means for you to post the definition of aTbName from your code; how is it declared? Typically, in VB6, that's the DIM statement, unless perhaps aTbName is the name of a textbox (or other control) on the form.

Comment: aTbName is the name of my textbox

Comment: @lancefelix Try setting the .Text property rather then the implied default properties. `Me.aTbName.Text = rs!Full_Name`

Answer (score 0):

The default property triggered for a TextBox is the `Text` property. So, if there is a TextBox with the name `Text1`, then this statement: `Text1 = "Hello"` would be equivalent to `Text1.Text = "Hello"`. But I always prefer using the property name along with the control name, when accessing it(ie, `Text1.Text = "Hello"`).

Anyway, test it out by using this line: `Me.aTbArrtime.text = rs!Full_Name`

Another thing that I have in mind is, if you have used some other component, say a custom made TextBox control (instead of the default one), and in the case of load failure, VB would replace the control(the custom made textbox) with a PictureBox in your forms. For checking that, click on the TextBox in the form and view it's properties. And see whether the control type is a TextBox. If it is a PictureBox, then double check whether your OCX or DLL for the custom made textbox is present in the project.

A small suggestion on your SQL code is that, you could have included the comparison in your query itself, instead of looping through all the records. For example:

```
.Source = "select * from Participants WHERE Bar_Code_No = " & Val(Me.aTbBar.Text) & " LIMIT 1"
```

This would return a single record if it matches the `Bar_Code_No`. After executing this query, you only need to check if it returns any record. If so, a match is found. Otherwise, no match is found. By this way, you can avoid looping, which might make your program Non-Responding if the number of records in the table `Participants` is enormously large !

Hope this would help you. Wish you good luck :)